# Customized installation of iPhone or Android application

Tags: iphone, android

I want to develop native mobile application in which user will send invitation to his friend to install another companion native application via a link to the application. But in order for this to work I need to pass a custom token or parameters in the link so that when the companion application is installed by the user's friend, this token is parsed by the companion application to display personalized message ( much like query string parameters are passed in the URL for normal web applications). Is this possible for iPhone and Android native applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible on stock iPhone/iOS devices.  App installation on iOS devices can only be done through the App Store app or iTunes, which do not accept any additional parameters other than the app identifier in the URLs they handle.